# Play Framework: SCSS file doesn't get compiled

Tags: playframework, sass

I have followed this guide: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsSass

But main.scss doesn't get compiled into css. There is no specific error on the browser or in the command line. But the css file doesn't get created.

Have tried the activator commands update, compile, clean, assets - none helped.

Would be extremely thankful if someone helped me with this problem.

Comment: a few questions -- what is the absolute path of your SASS file? (e.g. `app/assets/stylesheets/main.scss`) how are you sourcing the CSS file in the web page template? and have you required the sbt plugin `sbt-sassify`?

Comment: Actually it got solved somehow by itself. Perhaps I just needed to restart my computer. Thanks a lot anyways.